# Start with $1,000. Suppose you can flip a coin any number of times. Heads you quadruple your money. Tails you lose it all. How many times do you flip?

Tags: probability, ergodic-theory, paradoxes

Start with $1,000. Suppose you can flip a coin any number of times. Heads you quadruple your money. Tails you lose it all. How many times do you flip?

Comment: What is your objective? Or your utility function?

Comment: Make the plus $EV decision

Comment: What is your issue to compute the expected value? And you should precise if at each flip you play all the money or if you can play only part of it.

Comment: I think you can literally do no flips, and just walk away with $1000.

Comment: The point is that if i play indefinetely i am guaranteed to hit a tail some time, so my EV is zero?? what is the +EV decision?

Comment: all the money every flip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expectation of how much money you get after $n$ turns is $$\$\frac1{2^n}\times 4^n,000=\$2^n,000$$
so there is no point at which you stop playing the game at an advantage over continuing.

Answer (score 1):

No simple answer is known to this question, which is called the *St. Petersburg paradox*.

For detailed discussion of the issues, see [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox) or [the SEP article](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/paradox-stpetersburg/).